# Prove $h=$Log $z$ in a domain

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to show that if $h$ is analytic in $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z-1|<1\},$ $h'(z)=z^{-1},$ and $h(1)=0,$ then $h$ is Log $z$ in $D$. I know Log' $z=z^{-1}$ and Log $1=0.$ However, I don't know how to show $h$ must be Log $z$. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z \in D$ and $\gamma_z : [0,1] \to D$ be any continuously differentiable path with $\gamma_z(0) = 1, \gamma_z(1) = z$. You should be familiar with a theorem (I forgot the name - its analogous to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus in $\mathbb{R}$) which states that since $h'$ is holomorphic, we have

$$h(\gamma_z(1)) - h(\gamma_z(0)) = \int_{\gamma_z} h'(z') ~ d z'.$$

Hence,
\begin{align*}
h(z) & = h(z) - h(1) = h(\gamma_z(1)) - h(\gamma_z(0)) = \int_{\gamma_z} h'(z') ~ dz'\\
& = \int_{\gamma_z} \frac{1}{z'} ~ dz' = \log(z) - \log(1) = \log(z).
\end{align*}